# "Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" when deploying a JHipster app on Heroku

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, heroku, mariadb, jhipster

I have a JHipster/Spring monolithic site that I am trying to deploy to a Heroku free dyno with JawsDB Maria. I have JHipster configured to compile the project using Gradle on my local machine.

I'm getting this error:

```
2020-11-27T00:13:51.332601+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-11-27 00:13:51.329 ERROR 4 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig           : Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver from HikariConfig class classloader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@6d00a15d
2020-11-27T00:13:51.335652+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-11-27 00:13:51.335  WARN 4 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthContributorAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
2020-11-27T00:13:51.360451+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-11-27 00:13:51.360 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
2020-11-27T00:13:51.360453+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-27T00:13:51.360454+00:00 app[web.1]: ***************************
2020-11-27T00:13:51.360454+00:00 app[web.1]: APPLICATION FAILED TO START
2020-11-27T00:13:51.360455+00:00 app[web.1]: ***************************
2020-11-27T00:13:51.360455+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-27T00:13:51.360455+00:00 app[web.1]: Description:
2020-11-27T00:13:51.360456+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-27T00:13:51.360457+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:
2020-11-27T00:13:51.360458+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-27T00:13:51.360458+00:00 app[web.1]: Property: driverclassname
2020-11-27T00:13:51.360459+00:00 app[web.1]: Value: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
2020-11-27T00:13:51.360460+00:00 app[web.1]: Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
2020-11-27T00:13:51.360461+00:00 app[web.1]: Reason: Failed to load driver class com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
2020-11-27T00:13:51.360462+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-27T00:13:51.360462+00:00 app[web.1]: Action:
2020-11-27T00:13:51.360462+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-27T00:13:51.360463+00:00 app[web.1]: Update your application's configuration
2020-11-27T00:13:51.360463+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-27T00:13:51.487289+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-11-27T00:13:52.528199+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

The backend is written in Kotlin and uses MariaDB, while the frontend is written in Vue.js. I jave configured JHipster to compile the source code on my local machine.

This is the auto-generated `application-heroku.yml`:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: financial-services-station.herokuapp.com
    non-secure-port: 80
    prefer-ip-address: false
client:
    service-url:
    defaultZone: ${JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_URL}/eureka/

spring:
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: ${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
    username: ${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
    password: ${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    hikari:
    maximumPoolSize: 8
```

I already tried including `com.oracle.ojdbc:ojdbc10:19.3.0.0` in my gradle dependencies, which didn't fix it.

Comment: Your application-heroku.yml file is wrongly indented, I suppose it's just due to bad formatting in the question otherwise it would be a reason for your error. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting to learn how to properly format code blocks in your question.

Comment: _The backend is written in Kotlin and uses MariaDB_. Then why are you trying to include `com.oracle.ojdbc:ojdbc10:19.3.0.0` which happens to be oracle driver. I usually use `http://nexus.saas.hand-china.com/content/repositories/rdc` as the repository for ojdbc drivers

Comment: @kaushik Apologies as this is the first time I've tried making a web app on JVM, but what driver exactly am I supposed to be using to connect the site to MariaDB?

Comment: That depends upon the version of mariadb you are using . You can use it ilke `implementation("org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.7.1)`, if you are using version `2.7.1`. You can find other versions in [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client/2.7.1)